# How to catch 2 consecutive variable decreases?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to get the index of the element that started a 2 consecutive quarter decrease in GDP. My code runs, and returns a value of the expected type, but the value is wrong. There must be something I am missing in the computation...

Here is my data frame:

```
       Quarter      GDP  GDP 2009 $
0   2000q1  10031.0     12359.1
1   2000q2  10278.3     12592.5
2   2000q3  10357.4     12607.7
3   2000q4  10472.3     12679.3
4   2001q1  10508.1     12643.3
5   2001q2  10638.4     12710.3
6   2001q3  10639.5     12670.1
7   2001q4  10701.3     12705.3
8   2002q1  10834.4     12822.3
9   2002q2  10934.8     12893.0
    ....     ....        ....
```

Here is my code:

```
gdp_df['recession start'] = 0
i = 1
while i < (len(gdp_df)-1):
    row1 = gdp_df.iloc[i-1]
    row2 = gdp_df.iloc[i]
    row3 = gdp_df.iloc[i+1]
    if ((row3['GDP'] - row2['GDP']) < 0) and ((row2['GDP'] - row1['GDP']) < 0):
        gdp_df.iloc[i-1, 3] = 1
    i += 1
gdp_df = gdp_df.where(gdp_df['recession start'] == 1).dropna().iloc[0]
gdp_df = str(gdp_df['Quarter'])

return gdp_df
```

Comment: If your data contains two (or more) separate instances of decreasing GDP over two consecutive quarters, say for example 2004q2 to 2004q4 and also 2007q3 to 2008q1, which quarter do you want your code to return?  2004q2 or 2007q3?

Comment: Well they want a one string answer such as 2005q1, so I would assume there is only one

Comment: Your question is well placed, how would you approach it, if we needed to return a list of all recessions starter quarters?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in

```
gdp_df.iloc[i, 3] = 1
```

I was returning the 2nd value since i started by 1 and not 0.
The correct code is as such:
    gdp_df.iloc[i-1, 3] = 1